# Parse C byte array into Java ByteBuffer.

Tags: java, c, bytebuffer

I'm parsing a byte array which contains variables of different types. I'm getting this array from HID connected to my phone. Array was made by C programmer. I'm trying to parse it using ByteBuffer class:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
if(connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, buffer, 64, 1000) >= 0)
{
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    char mId = byteBuffer.getChar();
    short rId = byteBuffer.getShort();
    // ............................
}
```

But the values of this variables are not correct. Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I assume connection means you're getting it over a network? How about little- versus big-endianness, i.e., byte ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If byte order (little vs big endian) is the issue, you can set the byte order for the `ByteBuffer` to native without changing all of the program:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Set native byte order
char mId = byteBuffer.getChar();
short rId = byteBuffer.getShort();
```

On the other hand, if you find ByteBuffer objects more convenient than byte arrays, tell the C programmer to return you a [direct byte buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#new_direct_byte_buffer) instead of an array: easier for all parties and probably more efficient.

Comment: Some variables have type unsigned char or unsigned short. Is it correct to use methods getShort() or getChar() for them?

Comment: It's correct, the bits are the same. The sign affects only how the value is displayed or converted into wider types.

Comment: Now my issue is that there is only 1 byte for each char variable in byte buffer. So i can't use getChar() method because it makes char from 2 bytes. I'm trying to cast byte to char:    
    char c = (char) (byteBuffer.get() << 8);
But i'm still getting incorrect values of this char variables.

Comment: True, a char in C is a byte in Java. The part of the buffer that contains chars, does it stand for text? What is the character encoding?

Comment: No, it stands for numbers. 1 byte - 1 unsigned char variable.

Comment: Then use the byte type and the get method directly, no need to cast to char or do any bit shifts.

Comment: I was wrong - there are some 2-bytes char variables in that buffer, but when i'm trying to get their values using getChar(), i'm getting strange hieroglyphics instead of normal values(for instance, these char variables may have values such as '7A' or 'DF').

Answer (score 4):

There are systems with LitteEndian Byte order and BigEndian.

java uses BigEndian.

If the c programmer wrote the byte array in Little endian, you could use DataInputStream based on an Appache LittleEndianInputStream:

```
LittleEndianInputStream leis = new LittleEndianInputStream(is);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(leis);

int i1 = dis.readInt();
short s2 = dis.readShort();
```

If you and your colleague define a binary interface (file, or byte array) you always should force a speciifc byte order (Either little or big endian).